# How can I smoothen out these edges which I have extruded from 2 points ? Making the legendary donut

Tags: modeling

So I have been learning Blender and while making the legendary donut I have stumbled  upon this problem where I cannot make the edges smooth and they look all jagged. This happened while I was making the donut icing drips.

[image]

Comment: hello, it's hard to guess, maybe share your file (share the link it will give): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Try putting the solidify modifier below subdivision subsurface. But like moonboots said, it's really hard to guess from a single image. Blend file helps a lot